# request.session.flash() and .pop_flash()

Tags: python, pyramid

Whenever I POST a form, I display error messages. However, the way I add flashes to the queue, some messages stay after I POST to the form, and some don't. I noticed that it's due to the way I add messages to the queue.

The regular way that works perfectly:

```
post_data = request.POST
if 'submit' in post_data:
    ... function(post_data) ...
    if ...:
        request.session.flash(u'This is some error message')
    request.session.flash(u'Maybe some other error message')
```

And in the mako file:

```
<html>...<body>...
% for m in request.session.pop_flash():
  <div class="alert-message">
    <p>${m}</p>
  </div>
% endfor
...</body></html>
```

However, the way I want some of the messages to work is:

```
if 'submit' in post_data: 
    messages = function(...) # output is always a list
    for m in messages:
        request.session.flash(m)
```

When I do that, every time I rePOST to the same form, ALL the previous messages are added to the .flash() again. Thus, the error messages just keep piling. How do I fix this or work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem, but I'm not sure why it happened. Before, I initiated `message` as a keyword:

```
@classmethod
def validate(cls, message=[], **kwargs):
    if this:
        message.append(u'...')
    return kwargs, message
```

I believe that after each POST, `message` didn't clear even though I never called `validate()` with it. However, when I removed `messsage` as a keyword, it works fine:

```
@classmethod
def validate(cls, **kwargs):
    message = []
    ...
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: The reason is because you fell into a common "gotcha" in python of using a mutable object as a default argument. There are a ton of google results for this, but here's a good one: http://garybernhardt.blogspot.com/2006/12/default-arguments-are-tricky.html

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to answer this type of open-ended question with little context about its purpose. Typically the idea with a flash workflow is that you post to the form, then you redirect the user to a place where all of the flash messages are popped. What you are describing is posting multiple times and not necessarily popping the messages.

- You could have the view clear the flash queue before adding more stuff.
- You could pass some flag along with the POST?
- You could avoid using flash and roll something else for this use-case.

The reasons I can think why the flash queue is not getting cleared when you pop:

- You are returning your own response object that the session factory is failing to set the new updated session cookie on.
- Your code is generating an exception which could be causing the session factory to ignore cookie changes.

Comment: I am posting to a form on the same page, and if there are errors on the form, the same page pops up with messages above the form. If I post to the same form more than once (because I keep making errors), the error messages accumulate and do not refresh. I just tried not using flash and just accumulating a list of messages and passing it to the renderer, but taht didn't work either. Clearing the flash queue did not work since it already is cleared - the last block seems to re-add all the previous messages to the flash queue.

Comment: What session factory are you using?